# Inability to write import for Jama in java

Tags: java, matrix, jama

Tried to implement the example but I got the error in the title http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html

I'm just wondering how do I write the import for it. I haven't found anything online. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every Javadoc page, at the top, you have the name of the class, including its full path, which is what you should import.

For example, let's look at the well-known `ArrayList` class from the Java standard library. If you look at [its Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), you'll see:

```
java.lang.Object
    java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
        java.util.AbstractList<E>
            java.util.ArrayList<E>
```

By looking at the last line, you know you have to import `java.util.ArrayList` (generic type designators are not included in the import).

So now look at the Javadoc you gave us. It's a bit confusing, because ironically, the National Institute of Standards and Technology is not using the proper language conventions (the name of the package should have been `gov.nist.jama` or something like that, certainly not something that begins with a capital letter).

Nevertheless, the Javadoc states:

```
java.lang.Object
  └╴Jama.Matrix
```

So your import should be `Jama.Matrix`.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out i had to also download the source, i thought it was implicit. Thanks again.